# Water on top of biga

Tags: baking, bread, spoilage, biga

I made some [biga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biga_(bread_baking)) and used it once. There were some left overs, so I added more flour and a bit of water. There is now a layer of water on top of it, after I left it for a few days.

How do I know if it is off?

**Update:**
I think I'm making alcohol. I opened it and it smells like alcohol. I've mixed in the "water" layer on top and added more flour.

Lets see what happens?